# Does +1 to Gem level increase Mana cost

Tags: path-of-exile

Does adding a corresponding coloured gem to an item that has +1 Level to x type gem increase it's level and mana costs accordingly?

For example: If I have a weapon with +1 to strength gems and I add a cleave (lvl 5) gem will I incur the mana increase as if I'd levelled it from 5-6?

Comment: Isn't that dependent on the skill?

Comment: @deutschZuid It is, indeed.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102520/whats-the-point-of-leveling-gems-up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes if the skill uses mana it will likely increase (if the skill would increase it's mana cost normally too, i believe all skills that cost mana increase in mana cost when leveled up but do not nail me on that). You can check out all the gems on the wiki here: http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Gems#Gems